# Сосчитать многомерный массив

Tags: php, массивы

Массив формируется таким образом:

```
$arr[] = [1,2,3]
$arr[] = [2,3,5]
$arr[] = [1,1,1]
```

На выходе нужно получить один массив: `[4,6,9]`

Как сделать максимально красивее ?

Comment: и на основе какой упоротой логике должен получится такой исходящий массив?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сумма N-ых элементов подмассивов (суммируйте вертикально) :)

Comment: @php-mvc  Используйте декоративный шрифт, чтобы сделать максимально красиво!:)

Comment: @ZhukovRoman ммм.. ясно. Жаль, что ТС не смог этого объяснить

Comment: @php-mvc нужно ваще решение для сравнения, возможно красивее мы и не сможем написать

Comment: Сосчитать нужно все столбцы )   первый, второй, третий

Comment: @php-mvc У вас только три пальца на руке?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $value1lvl) {
    foreach ($value1lvl as $key2lvl=>$value2lvl) {
       if (!isset($sum[$key2lvl])) {$sum[$key2lvl]=0;}     
       $sum[$key2lvl]=$sum[$key2lvl]+$value2lvl;
    }
}
```

Демо - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a27992153fdfc46fc4b36242b619347f25a9b768